# Running the ZK essentials maven project from eclipse

Tags: zk

I usually can run zk apps on the server but the essentials app is a maven project and I cant see that option in zk studio (in eclipse).

How do I run it in eclipse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install the m2e plugin from the marketplace. It will give you additional options in the Run menu like "Maven install".

Note that Maven is a *build* tool, not a *run* tool. Maven only manages the classpath for you. You can then use the normal "Run as ..." of Eclipse to start it.

**EDIT** When you have m2e, make sure you import the project using "Import Maven project". M2e will then configure all the aspects, facets and natures.

If you already have the project imported, try "Update Project..."

If that doesn't work, try to enable the "Web Project Facet". See this blog post for details: http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-java-project-to-web-project-in-eclipse/

Comment: thanks I have that, I only see the options run as > {Java applet, Java app, maven build, maven ... etc } There is no run on server  (Tomcat install)like the  projects created with ZK studio.

Comment: many thanks, it is already a xk project and couldn't see the web facets option but I get this error when trying to run it (the run on server option now appears): **Could not delete C:/Users/me/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/test2/WEB-INF/lib. May be locked by another process.**

Comment: make sure you don't run the server twice and make sure it has stopped properly and completely before trying to start it again.

Answer (score 1):

I have installed  m2e plugin  on  Eclipse Juno without any problem.
Have you tried   install  m2e plugin  before install other plugins? it
will give you maven  install option .

first of all, goto  help  menu then   eclipse marketplace search 
m2e plugin  in eclipse juno/ kepler version and install the m2e plugin